# Word for people who live in the same city

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What are the people who live in the same city are called? Any words for that?
I want to use it in the following context:

> I and my ____ are happy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there IS NO single-word solution there in English.  You'd have to say something like "Me and everyone else who lives here is happy."

Comment: Pls refer also to: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19722/one-who-lives-in-the-same-city-in-relation-to-another-person/19723#19723

Comment: If you're going to use proper English, you need to say, "My XXXXs and I are happy."

Comment: @Panzer: that is not any more proper. It is exactly as proper.

Comment: Has it changed recently?  There was a pretty big deal made out of it while I was in different schools in the 90's and the 00's.

Comment: @Panzercrisis is right. The correct English is "My ___ and I are...".

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Compared to the question, Panzer's sentence is a slight improvement.  Compared to Joe's comment, ... still looking for that comment downvote button :(

Comment: I was just looking for a simple word to be used in a sentence in a scientific paper. Didn't know it would make such a big problem! :)

Answer (score 32):

**Townsfolk**

> I and my fellow townsfolk are happy.

*Citizens* is also a possibility, but could be misinterpreted.

Comment: Note that using "fellow" here is required to convey the meaning desired by the OP. "Townsfolk" on its own does not convey that meaning.

Comment: But what are you going to say if it is a large city like Chicago or Manchester? Townsfolk doesn't really work for anywhere much bigger than Chipping Sodbury, Gloucestershire. 'Citizens' has acquired a different meaning. It was once associated with a city state. But one doesn't talk about the 'citizens of London'. Nations have citizens, not cities.

Comment: I've heard `city folk` used... sounds kind of odd like this though. Usually in contrast to `country folk`

Answer (score 25):

I think the word you need is 'denizens'.

'The **denizens** of Boston showed great solidarity in the face of a terrorist attack'.

'I and my fellow **denizens** are happy'.

Comment: One of my favorite words, but I think it needs qualification to have the meaning the OP seeks.

Comment: I agree with *denizens*; I think it is probably the closest to what the OP is asking for. If you want a single word, you could maybe get away with 'co-denizens', but I don't really like that; it doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Spudley Doesn't sound right to me either. I thought 'fellow denizens'. It is two words but as far as I know there is no tax on the number of words you use.

Answer (score 20):

Typically the way to say this is:

**Fellow** [name for locals]

For example:

> I want to make my fellow New Yorkers happy.

Comment: I don't want to mention any cities. Is it possible to say "make my fellows happy?"

Comment: My original sentence is similar to: "And individual and his XXXXs are ...."

Comment: You can not use "fellows" alone without a city name, it would make no sense.

Comment: *'fellow residents of X'*?

Comment: @Shayan Fellow citizens, perhaps

Answer (score 11):

*Locals* is also applicable, as in ,

> Locals of Chocmallow Town

Comment: This word also works without specifying a city:  "The locals and I are..."

Answer (score 9):

You can use ***townspeople*** or ***townsfolk***.

> the people who live in a town or city.

Answer (score 8):

I would have to advocate the word `citizen(s)` as it really is the correct word, common-place parlance has reduced/expanded (depending on you point of view) its validity, however the word still stands as being the correct term for an inhabitant of a city.  The word `fellow` can be used to indicate an affinity or shared membership of a group; hence, in the context of the phrase mentioned by the OP it would be more appropriate to utilise a two word insertion to clarify the meaning:

### `I and my ____ are happy.`:

`I and my citizens are happy.` - this makes it appear that the citizens belong to the writer, perhaps not the image/meaning intended to be conveyed.

`The citizens and I are happy.` - this makes the writer and the citizens appear to be happy, although no affiliation is implied or inferred.

`I and my fellow citizens are happy.` - this states writer and citizens are both happy whilst also delineating that the writer wishes his status as a part of their group to be known, although this shared status is proprietorial and is from his/her view only and does not indicate the citizens feel the same way.

As Josh61 already mentioned there is a very similar chat going on [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/19748/5275)

### Addendum:

Paraphrasing from [one of my other posts](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/19748/5275):

The popular usage of citizen (a person who lives in a particular town or city, originally a concatenation of the word city and denizen, cit(y)-(den)izen => cit-izen => citizen) actually makes citizen mean the same as national (someone who officially belongs to a particular country).  This does not however, alter the original meaning of the word, which remains (from the Oxford dictionary) `"An inhabitant of a particular town or city:"` exemplar usage: `the good citizens of Edinburgh`.

Therefore in correct English I would be a citizen of Glasgow if I lived in Glasgow and a British national/countryman/compatriot (dependant on convection of specific meaning required) if I lived in Britain.

Analysis of the etymology of the word allows for the conclusions, as well as the fact that I am quite particular in word usage.  I understand language evolves over time (the modern usage is more ambiguous than the original meaning), however, the original context and meaning can still be utilised to be concise and to the point.

In regards to the evolution of language, I agree it happens however that does not preclude any given person being aware of past or lesser used meanings and utilising them to illustrate a point or create a precision and disambiguity in their language (for example,  the word `idiot` stems from the Greek *`idiotai`* which was an appellation indicating a private citizen(hence the reason for its use as an example here): over the span of the Greek era it evolved to mean a person holding no official role in public forums, then later as a term for people who did not cast votes at public referenda, and later as a term of disparagement of belittlement, much as it is used today.

### Etymology:

citizen (n.) 
early 14c., "inhabitant of a city," from Anglo-French citezein (spelling subsequently altered, probably by influence of denizen), from Old French citeien "city-dweller, town-dweller, citizen" (12c., Modern French citoyen), from cite (see city) + -ain (see -ian). Replaced Old English burhsittend and ceasterware. Sense of "inhabitant of a country" is late 14c. Citizen's arrest recorded from 1941; citizen's band (radio) from 1947. Citizen of the world (late 15c.) translates Greek kosmopolites.

from [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=citizen)

**Etymological diagram:**

[image: Etymology of citizen]

Online sources utilised as to provide alternate proof to English language etymology texts (My books do not fit in the scanner)

**Physical sources:**

- Chambers Dictionary of Etymology
- The Oxford Dictionary of English Etymology

Comment: Citizens is more to do with countries or civilisations than a town/city

Comment: citizen has more to do with cities in its proper meaning, however, it is true that in modern usage it has had its meaning expanded to allow people a more dumbed-down subset of vocabulary to encompass a greater scope.  If you analyse the vocabularic usage of a random cross section of the populace nowadays I think you may be shocked by how limited and abbreviation-filled it is.

Comment: OED lists both definitions with the city based one as the alternate so I'm not sure how you can call that the 'proper' definition and the main usage 'dumbed-down'. Changes in use are not incorrect use and this is not even a recent one. Language evolves, deal with it.

Comment: I have no problem with linguistic evolution, nor any incapacity to 'deal with it' seems like a rather bellicose response to a simple statement of informed opinion; however, you are of course free to your opinion and seemingly pugnacious nature.  The dumbing down of meaning is simply intended due to the dilution of vocabulary to a smaller and smaller subset, again, no problem with that for casual conversation, however it is meet to have a broader spectrum to draw from when writing or engaging in formal discourse, or when looking for a breviloquent alternative.

Comment: However much you want to obfuscate what you are saying with extraneous words that you have read in a thesaurus, and regardless of it's heritage, the word in question simply does not carry the meaning in common usage.  People would not understand your intended implication and while you can try and beautify what you are saying with fancy vocabulary, at the end of the day none of that is any use if you fail to communicate.

Comment: Clearly the word 'citizen' has followed a journey to arrive at where it is today. The OED says: A civilian as distinguished from a soldier; in earlier times also distinguished from a member of the landed nobility or gentry. Johnson says ‘a man of trade, not a gentleman’.
This was undoubtedly its original meaning in Britain, and inherited by America. However my feeling is that the great event in world history that carried 'citizen' to its supreme status which it enjoys today was the French Revolution. It is synonymous with the nationalism and concomitant elevation of the citizen to power. cont

Comment: 'People power' exploded into prominence with the Tennis Court revolutionaries. The Habsburgs, the Hohenzollerns, and all the Princes of Europe quaked in their shoes at the sound of the hooves of Napoleon's cavalry; and the Marseillaise, with its thunderous crescendo of 'Aux armes citoyens'. The age of the common 'citizen' was born. It would take Britain and America another 70 years to the days of Lincoln and Disraeli, to grasp what the French Revolution had released. We now live in the age of the 'citizen', who is no longer merely a 'city dweller' but the essence of the power of the state.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from a comment made by the OP

> My original sentence is similar to: "And individual and his XXXXs are
>   ...."

- This citizen and his **compatriots** are ...
- This townsman/woman and their **fellow townsmen** are ...
- This dweller and **the people who live locally** are ...
- This individual and the **local residents** are ...

Answer (score 3):

*'fellow residents of X'*

There is no one-word way, and also no natural-sounding way to say it without naming the city.

or *'fellow New Yorkers/Bostonians/San Franciscans/Dubliners/Londoners/Parisians/...'*
if there is a specific noun for residents of that city.

Comment: This is good, too. I'm glad you posted it separately instead of just as a comment on my post.

Answer (score 0):

> Now everyone who lives here is happy.

or

> Now everyone who lives here, including me, is happy.

Maybe take out "now."

Answer (score 0):

I suggest 'townies'
usage ' the townies are going nuts because the high school football team is going to the state finals'

In New England, there is a distinction between townies and other people, usually students or tourists who are in the area for less than a lifetime. The movie Good Will Hunting is about a townie whose talents take him away from the life he expected to lead.

Comment: While accurate, it is worth mention that townie has a number of connotations that skew its meaning.

- It's used by rural folks to identify city-folk
- It's used by university students to identify the non-student population of a college/university town
- It's used by city folks to identify rural folk

Answer (score 0):

For some cities, a common way today is to use their demonym, e.g. [cityname][modifier], e.g.

- Bostonians
- New Yorkers
- Chigacoans
- Bedfordians
- Cantabrigian
- Torontonian

Full list at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectivals_and_demonyms_for_cities

Answer (score 0):

There can also be cultural implications. Filipinos, for example, routinely refer to their fellow "townmates."

For Americans, if the people of a city have a commonly used name, such as "Chicagoans," then words like that would fit, nicely... as another answerer, here, wrote.

Beyond that, I think it's a question of figuring out what city-specific name ties everyone, and figuring out how to put it into the proper tense.

I also agree with those who insist that it should be "My ***_*__** and I are happy."

For whatever any of that is worth.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Denizens** has possible negative connotations and possibly **townsfolk** suggests too small a location for **city dwellers** so maybe that is it!

Answer (score 0):

Man I am answering this late and there is no steam left but why not...In WWII documentaries I hear soldiers giving shout-outs to other soldiers from their same hometown.  The soldiers would refer to them as their "**home boys**".

> Usage:
>
> My home boy from Akron is a great pilot.